# NGINX location directives for the same location

Tags: nginx, nexus, nginx-location

I have a Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.0 running behind NGINX as a private docker registry.  My Docker client (not the official docker client) is expecting a `200 OK` and an empty JSON string `{}` to be returned from `/v2/`.  The problem i'm running into is that Nexus returns the `200 OK` but an empty string.

My work-around is to have NGINX return a file containing an empty JSON string for `/v2/` requests and proxy `/v2/*` requests to Nexus.

```
server {
  listen               443 ssl;
  server_name          nexus.example.com;
  ssl_certificate      ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  ssl/server.key;

  location = /v2/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/www;
    index empty.json;
  }

  location /v2/ {
    proxy_pass                          http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout                  900;
  }
}
```

I would expect this to work, but it directs all traffic (`/v2/, /v2/_catalog, /v2/myimage/manifests/latest`, etc) to the proxy_pass.  How can I make `/v2/` requests go to the location to sever the `empty.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have placed a file at `/home/ubuntu/www/v2/empty.json`?

The problem is that the `index` directive will rewrite the URI to `/v2/empty.json` which is then processed by the `location /v2/` block.

One solution would be to create another location to match the rewritten URI and serve it as a static file:

```
root /home/ubuntu/www;

location = /v2/ {
    index empty.json;
}
location = /v2/empty.json {
}
```

Another solution is to use the `error_page` directive. But you will still need to specify a `location` and `root` to handle the static file(s):

```
location = /v2/ {
    return 405;
    error_page 405 =200 /static/empty.json;
}
location / {
    root /home/ubuntu/www;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes all the sense in the world!  I went with the first solution you proposed and it works great.